# Pulling Information from a Parsed XML File that's NOT in the same array but always the following

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I'm looking to pull the value below `RO_XV100` into my script. My problem is that it's not in the same array, it's always listed immediately after it so I don't know how to grab it. I would like to know if there is a way to look for the NEXT `parameters` tag and pull the value @value.

Snip of what I'm Parsing.

```
               <momentaryButton name="MomentaryPushButton7"  description="Valve Force Toggle" >
             </momentaryButton>
            <parameters>
                <parameter name="#1" description="Valve Tag" value="RO_XV100"/>
            </parameters>
```

Here is a Snip of the  Perl.

```
  foreach my $title ($doc->findnodes('//momentaryButton')) {
    my $sec;
    my @securitylevels= ();
    my $button = $title->findvalue('@description');
    $sec = "G";
    }
    print_latex($i,$button,"Momentary Push Button",$sec,"N\/A","N\/A");
    $i++;
  }
```

Thanks for any help.
I'm using:

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::Parser;
```

Comment: Can you show a complete (minimal) XML file ? Also try to show a complete minimal Perl script. See [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

XPath `//foo/bar` is short for `/descendant::foo/child::bar`. `descendant` and `child` are called "search axes". You achieve what you want by searching the `following-sibling` axis.

```perl
for my $button_node ($doc->findnodes('//momentaryButton')) {
   my $button_text = $button_node->getAttribute('description');
 
   my $param_val = $doc->findvalue(
      'following-sibling::parameters/parameter[1]/@value', $button_node);
 
   print_latex($i, $button_text, "Momentary Push Button", $sec, "N/A", "N/A");
   ++$i;
}
```

If you'd prefer to locate the parameter by name rather than by position, you can use the following XPath instead:

```xml
following-sibling::parameters/parameter[@name="#1"]/@value
```

Comment: Thanks Ikegami! I was able to get it to work with your answer. Much appreciated

Comment: No problem. This is usually communicated by checking the mark next to the answer.